# How to use all buttons into one, using C#

Tags: c#

I have a lot of buttons in my project. To make the program code shorter, I have made every click of a button to the same `Button_click()` method. I want all this buttons lead into one function but with `if` statement.

Inside `Button_click()`, how can I identify which button has been pressed in the Mymethod method?

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

    xlexcel.Visible = false;

    xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:WIP.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Item";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "Product";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "Year";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = "Month IN";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5] = "Month OUT";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 6] = "WK IN";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 7] = "WK OUT";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 8] = "Date";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 9] = "System S/N";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 10] = "ChassisorMotherboardS/N";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 11] = "TYPE";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 12] = "Part-NuMotherboarder";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 13] = "Logfiles w/ Unit";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 14] = "Problem/failure Reported by CTO/BTO/QS";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 15] = "FVT Diagnostics";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 16] = "Reproduce the failure";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 17] = "FVT comments";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 18] = "FVT comments for Absolut";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 19] = "FVT Part Number";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 20] = "FVT Serial number";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 21] = "FVT Tech";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 22] = "Disposition";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 23] = "Date Sent Out";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 24] = "Failure Category";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 25] = "Aging";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 26] = "aging ov";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 27] = "Final comments";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 28] = "Contributor";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 29] = "Ports";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 30] = "Status";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 31] = "QTY";

}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 1] = textItem.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 2] = textProduct.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 3] = textYear.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 4] = textMonthIN.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 5] = textMonthOUT.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 6] = textWKIN.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 7] = textWKOUT.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 8] = textDate.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 9] = textSystemSN.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 10] = textChassisorMotherboardSN.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 11] = textTYPE.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 12] = textPartNuMotherboarder.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 13] = textLogfileswUnit.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 14] = textProblemfailureReportedbyCTOBTOQS.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 15] = textFVTDiagnostics.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 16] = textReproducethefailure.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 17] = textFVTcomments.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 18] = textFVTcommentsforAbsolut.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 19] = textFVTTech.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 20] = textFVTPartNumber.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 21] = textFVTSerialnumber.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 22] = textDisposition.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 23] = textDateSentOut.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 24] = textFailureCategory.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 25] = textAging.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 26] = textagingov.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 27] = textFinalcomments.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 28] = textContributor.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 29] = textPorts.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 30] = textStatus.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 31] = textQTY.Text;


}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = @"C:WIP.xlsx"; 
    xlWorkBook.SaveCopyAs(fileName);
    xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
    xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
    xlexcel.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlexcel);
}

private void releaseObject(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = null;
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //File.Copy(@"C:\test.xlsx", @"C:\test.xlsx");

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:p\test.xlsx");
    string destDir = @"C:\other\";
    FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(destDir, file.Name));
    if (destFile.Exists)
    {
        if (file.LastWriteTime > destFile.LastWriteTime)
        {
            file.CopyTo(destFile.FullName, true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        File.Copy(@"C:\test.xlsx", @"C:\test.xlsx");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just need to know which element invoked the event, the `sender` object should be that element.  But it's not clear what you're really trying to accomplish here or why.

Comment: Don't worry about making your code nicer for now, it will come with time and experience. Start doing bigger projects with more complex problems and you will soon find that you *have* to organize your code in some fashion, and you will. But what you're asking to do here is just weird, out of context.

Comment: ((Button)sender).Name

Comment: thanks. Can you give an example please, Could be something like this :
 
((button5_Click)sender).button4;
?

Comment: From a code maintenance perspective this is a bad idea. Using a shared handler for all buttons presents the risk that if a button is not producing the correct effect, fixing the shared handler may break the processing for other buttons. I prefer to have a handler per button and put any shared processing they may have in a private method that is called from within the handlers that need it. Much cleaner to debug and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Kevin's comment, that each button should have its own handler. Here is some code that should do what you want.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string buttonName = string.Empty;
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            buttonName = button.Name;
        }

        if (buttonName == "button1")
        {

        }
        else if (buttonName == "button2")
        {

        }
    }
```